# Jquery - Select one element (on click) between other elements that share the same class name

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm trying to figure out somethig. I'm doing an e-shop for my school project. I have done almost all scripting, but this one is that buggers me so much.

I have a class for all the items, meaning that items from 1 to 10 have the same class name. When I want to add to the cart, I click and there will be a $.post behind doing all the magic. The thing is, that it only selects the **first** element with that class name. I have searched on the web about that, and all I found was "select all elements with same class name" or "select elements within parent element". What I want it to do is select individual elements that share the same class name.
 I'll post the code here, thanks :)

```
$(".adicionar_ao_carrinho").bind("click",function(){
    $(this).each(function(){
    var a =  $("[name='item']").val(); //debugg purpose
    alert(a); //debugg purpose
        $.post("ajax/carrinho.php",
        {
            id: $("[name='item']").val(),
            preco: $("[name='preco']").val(),
            qtd: $("[name='quantidade']").val(),
            user: <?php echo $_SESSION['uid']; ?>
        },function(data){
                alert(data);
            }
        )

    });
});
```

**EDIT:**

```
<div class=\"adicionar_artigo\">
    <form method='post'>
        <input type='text' name='quantidade' size='1' value='1'/>
        <a href=\"#\" name=\"trigger\" class=\"adicionar_ao_carrinho\"><img src=\"ficheiros/images/icons/adicionar_1.png\" /></a>
        <input type='hidden' name='item' value='$id_artigo' />
        <input type='hidden' name='preco' value='$preco' />
    </form>
</div>
```

Each item has a form like this one.

**EDIT2:** http://s14.postimg.org/w29v5x2fl/error.png

 
this explains better

Comment: `$(this)` represents the element that is being clicked on.

Comment: True, but still doesn't work

Comment: I'm not even sure I understand what's happening in your code..where is this not working?

Comment: Are you saying the click only works on one element, or that you only get the value from the first element (btw, val() only gets the value from the first element in the collection) ?

Comment: When I click "<a href=\"#\" name=\"trigger\" class=\"adicionar_ao_carrinho\"><img src=\"ficheiros/images/icons/adicionar_1.png\" /></a>", only responds to the first element, while I have like 5 elements and it should respond to each individually

Comment: Also, you can only click one element, so `this` is just one element, and a loop is uneccessary.

Comment: And while I'm at it, don't echo out session variables like that, you can access those on the serverside, you don't have to send the session ID with ajax.

Comment: I don't start the session on the "carrinho.php" file, that's why I send it through $.post.

And btw, yes, it only works for one element, the first one

Comment: Can you post your HTML structure for reference, please.

Comment: So the alert is showing if you click any element with that class? That means the event handler is working, but `val()` is getting the value of the first element in the collection just like I wrote two hours ago. See my edited answer below for a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done it.
Changed html:

```
<div class=\"adicionar_artigo\">
    <a href=\"#\" class=\"adicionar_ao_carrinho\">
        <img src=\"ficheiros/images/icons/adicionar_1.png\" />
    </a>
    <input type='hidden' name='preco' value='$preco' />
    <input type='hidden' name='item' value='$artigo[ID_artigo]' />
    <input type='text' name='quantidade' size='1' value='1'/>
</div>
```

And also changed jquery:

```
$(".adicionar_ao_carrinho").bind("click",function(){
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    $.post("ajax/carrinho.php",
    {
        id: $("input[name='item']",parent).val(),
        preco: $("input[name='preco']",parent).val(),
        qtd: $("input[name='quantidade']",parent).val(),
        user: "<?php echo $_SESSION['uid']; ?>"
    },function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    )
});
```

And it's working.
Thank for the help and effort of everyone! :)

Answer (score 1):

I'll take a wild guess, your code fails on the first click because this:

```
user: <?php echo $_SESSION['uid']; ?>
```

outputs an unquoted string, and should be:

```
user: "<?php echo $_SESSION['uid']; ?>"
```

which would leave you with:

```
$(".adicionar_ao_carrinho").on("click",function(){
    var form = $(this).closest('form'),
        data = {
        id   : $("[name='item']", form).val(),
        preco: $("[name='preco']", form).val(),
        qtd  : $("[name='quantidade']", form).val(),
        user : "<?php echo $_SESSION['uid']; ?>"
    }    
    $.post("ajax/carrinho.php", data ,function(result){
        console.log(result);
    }).fail(function(a,b,c) {
        console.log('ajax failed');
    });
});
```

Comment: shouldn't wild guesses be a comment?

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui - explaining how a selector works, when the OP has the right selector certainly should.

Comment: Tried, still not working. But anyway thanks, forgot about those :)

Comment: @Sashka - And these elements are of course not inserted with javascript later ?

Comment: no. I just do a var_export() on the other file (carrinho.php) for debbug purposes. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".class_name")
```

### Explanation:

The dot in that code specifies that now we are talking about the classes and then the class_name is ofcourse the class name shared by the other elements. Like in your case the `class_name` is `adicionar_ao_carrinho` so then the above code will be changed into this one: `$("a.adicionar_ao_carrinho");`

---

More specifically if it is a div or a span or anything else you may change the above like this:

For div: `$("div.class_name");`
For span: `$("span.class_name");`

### Explanation:

And this goes for all other elements. But the above will work right as well if the class is used for just a single element but you might need the second one if different elements are using the same elements.

**Update:**
After seeing your HTML I see that your class_name is different that you told! So it should be this: `$("div.adicionar_artigo");`

Comment: "<a href=\"#\" name=\"trigger\" class=\"adicionar_ao_carrinho\"><img src=\"ficheiros/images/icons/adicionar_1.png\" /></a>"

This is the line, so suppose, it should be $("a.class_name"); ?

Tried and still didn't work

Comment: @Sashka no! it should be this: `$("a.adicionar_ao_carrinho");`

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, I was just following your example! :)

Comment: can you post what you wrote?

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you mean with "can you post what you wrote?" ?

Comment: I mean please post what you replaced in your code with my one?

Comment: $(".adicionar_ao_carrinho").bind("click",function(){});___Html is already there posted

Comment: adding the elements tagname will just slow down the selector, as lookup is from the right to the left, so first it finds all elements with that class, and now it has to filter them by tagName as well.

Comment: @adeneo but then if another element is having the same class it will effect them aswell!

Comment: @Mohammad I've seen your edit and the class name is not different, because I do the bind on the tag <a> not on the <div>. Even so, doing the way your edit didn't work unfortunetly : /

Comment: I think it could be probably stored in cache somehow ?

Comment: @Sashka I didn't understand! WHat do you mean? You want it to be stored in the cache?

Comment: No no no. I meant It COULD somehow be stored. I mean, every time a click the <a> tag it SHOULD call the $.post function with different values since they are different items, but it does't, it calls always the first element it founds! Example: Item1-price:25;id:15;___Item2-price:27;id:17. Instead of calling individually, it always calls the same id, which in this example is 15. That is what is happening to me, instead of calling individual elements, it just calls for the first one it founds with that class name

Comment: Can you give me the URl of the site or it is on your local machine? I want that so I can see the error myself..

Comment: Ok! So when you click on that image then that occurs?

Comment: Yes, exactly. It appears ID=7. If I click the last item it SHOULD appear ID=10 but it appears ID=7. And it's exactly the same for the others.

Comment: It's in the original post, up there :)

Comment: I think you are missing some thing in this: `$("[name='item']").val(); ` dont you want a selector name here!

Comment: Try this: `$("a.adicionar_ao_carrinho[name='item']").val();`

Comment: Or try this: `$($(this) + "[name='item']").val();`

Comment: That is not necessary because I'm doing $(this).each(){}, and in the each I'm doing it automatically, so it does what you have wrote. But I tried anyway to test and failed too.